# PostgreSQL two tables with expressions relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a need to do relations between two tables with binary expressions between them. I'll try to clarify. Got two tables

```
--First
id | Name
1  | First Test 1
2  | First Test 2

--Second
id | Name
1  | Second Test 1
2  | Second Test 2
```

I want to be able to link the two tables with a logical expressions like the below pseudo code:

```
First(id=1) => Second(id=1) && (AND) Second(id=2)
```

Something like one-to-many but with logical operator between all the relations. Is there a straight forward way of doing this?

Thanks in advance,

Julian

- UPDATE:
  As @Rezu requested - To be able to write a query that will return a text for example:

```
First Test 1 := Second Test 1 AND Second Test 2
```

the `AND` part can be `AND`, `OR`, `NOT` etc.

Hope this clarify the thing that I want to achieve

- UPDATE 1:
  [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0ee4c/1) is almost the thing I like to achieve. The result query is this:

```
First Test 1 := Second Test 1
First Test 1 := Second Test 2
First Test 2 := Second Test 3
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
First Test 1 := Second Test 1 AND First Test 1 := Second Test 2
First Test 2 := Second Test 3
```

Hope that explains what is my goal

Comment: add expected result too please.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "need to do relations"? Do you want to define a foreign key constraint? Do you want to join the table in a single query?

Comment: I've updated the question with hopefully understandable expected result. Thanks

Comment: Can you make an example? It's absolutely not clear what do you want to achieve...

Comment: @S-Man I Updated again the question

Comment: There is no `Second Test 3` in your input data.

Comment: Row 14 and 15 - `insert into second (name) values (
'Second Test 1'),('Second Test 2'),('Second Test 3');` or it is not visible to you, because to me it is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/56caf/4) is my solution. Maybe there is a better one, but this is what I came up with

```sql
create table first (
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);

insert into first (name) values (
'First Test 1'),('First Test 2');

create table second (
    id serial primary key,
    name text
);

insert into second (name) values (
'Second Test 1'),('Second Test 2'),('Second Test 3');

create table first_second (
    first_id bigint,
    second_id bigint,
    logical_operator text
);

insert into first_second (first_id, second_id,logical_operator) values (
1,1,''),(1,2,'AND'),(2,3,'');
```

And the query is:

```sql
SELECT first.name || ' := ' || 
string_agg(first_second.logical_operator || ' ' || second.name, ' ') 
as name
FROM 
  first
 JOIN first_second ON first_second.first_id = first.id
 JOIN second ON first_second.second_id = second.id
 Group by first.name
```